# Can't import 'views' from 'urls' - Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to import 'views' file to my 'urls' so I could map the path to this 'vehicle_validation' function.
For some reason, pycharm can't find this file.
can someone help me understand what's the problem?

urls file:

```
from django.urls import path
from vehicule_approver import views # error here

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('vehicle_validation/', views.vehicle_validation)
]
```

views file:

```
import requests
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
from pyapi.vehicule_approver.models import Vehicle

def vehicle_validation(request): 
...
```

project structure:
[structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZsul.png)

Comment: You need to include the name of the app, so `from appname.vehicule_approver import views`

Comment: I'm still getting an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyapi.vehicule_approver'

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem cames from the import of `vehicule_approver` you used in `views.py`.
With `from vehicule_approver import views` Python tries to find a module `vehicule_approver` inside your `sys.path`.

Perhaps use one of those imports:

```py
from ..vehicule_approver import views # Relative import
from pyapi.vehicule_approver import views # Absoute import
```

Comment: Thanks, now I'm not getting pycharm error but when I try to 'runserver' I'm gitting the error:
    from ..vehicule_approver import views
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

```
from pyapi.vehicule_approver.models import Vehicle
```

Imports should be relative to the project directory (the one that contains `manage.py`), so you should remove the `pyapi` and change the import to:

```
from vehicule_approver.models import Vehicle
```

Alternatively, since you are importing from the same app, you can use a relative import.

```
from .models import Vehicle
```